# Trying to figure out error message with divide -Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, numbers, typeclass

I am new to Haskell and I am getting error trying to divide result of `truncate` with a number. I am not sure what are the number types after truncation and why my division is failing. Thank you.

```
-- Create 10^n
tens :: Int -> Integer
tens n = fromIntegral(product (take n [10, 10 .. ]))

-- Rounds list of numbers to n decimal places
rd n x = map (\r -> truncate(r * (tens n)) `div` (tens n)) x

main = do
  -- expected output: [2.12, 3.45, 4.67]
  print (rd 2 [2.123,3.456,4.675])
```

Error message:

> ```
> main.hs:8:21: error:
>     • No instance for (RealFrac Integer)
>         arising from a use of ‘truncate’
>     • In the first argument of ‘div’, namely ‘truncate (r * (tens n))’
>       In the expression: truncate (r * (tens n)) `div` (tens n)
>       In the first argument of ‘map’, namely
>         ‘(\ r -> truncate (r * (tens n)) `div` (tens n))’
>   |
> 8 | rd n x = map (\r -> truncate(r * (tens n)) `div` (tens n)) x
>   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> main.hs:11:16: error:
>     • No instance for (Fractional Integer)
>         arising from the literal ‘2.123’
>     • In the expression: 2.123
>       In the second argument of ‘rd’, namely ‘[2.123, 3.456, 4.675]’
>       In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
>         ‘(rd 2 [2.123, 3.456, 4.675])’
>    |
> 11 |   print (rd 2 [2.123,3.456,4.675])
>    |                ^^^^^
> <interactive>:3:1: error:
>     • Variable not in scope: main
>     • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
> ```

Comment: `10^n` is valid Haskell, no need to reinvent it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your division is failing because your truncation is failing before it. You have

```
              tens    :: Int  ->                    Integer
              tens (n :: Int) ::                    Integer
          r * tens  n         ::                    Integer
          r                   ::                    Integer
truncate :: (            RealFrac a, Integral b) => a        ->               b
truncate (r * tens  n :: RealFrac Integer        => Integer) :: Integral b => b
```

i.e. your code is saying there must be a `RealFrac Integer` instance defined in scope. But there isn't, is what the error message is telling you.

We usually truncate floating point numbers, to get their whole portion as an `Integral` type value, but the argument `r * tens n` is already an integer.